# How does this Expression Simplify to $\frac1n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, factorial

A somewhat trivial question;

How does the following simplify to $\frac1n$?

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac1n$$

I'm just not seeing the algebra/operations. Is there a way to expand $!(n-1)$?

Comment: Basically,$$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{1\cdot 2\cdot \dots \cdot (n-2)(n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot \dots \cdot (n-2)(n-1)\color{red}n} = \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Cheers! This makes sense.

Comment: $n(n-1)!=n!$ (cross-multiplied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\dots(n-2)\cdot(n-1)\phantom{\ \cdot n}}{1\cdot2\cdot3\dots(n-2)\cdot(n-1)\cdot n}=\boxed{\frac 1n}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now.

Comment: @gargle12345, the standard way to thank people on this site is to upvote and/or accept their answers.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to wait a few more minutes before I can accept the answer (shenanigans for people with new accounts, I presume), and apparently I don't have enough reputation to upvote either. Sorry.